# Записать стэктрейс ошибки в отдельный файл на ruby

Tags: ruby

Как записать стэктрейс ошибки в отдельный файл на ruby?

Использую RubyMine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
  1/0
rescue => e
  File.open "backtrace.txt", "w" do |f|
    f.puts e.backtrace
  end
end
```